# Can I change the projectID of an existing task in atTask API v2?

Tags: rest, attask

I wanna connect an existing task to another project per REST-Api. I am trying to make a put-call like this:

```
PUT https://attask-server/attask/api/task/24252...5?sessionID=4e7...8dee&projectID=54f....2d
```

But there is no change after that, I am using API v2, maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in oder to do this you would need to use the MOVE action

```
PUT /attask/api/TASK/553fe53.../move?projectID=54945...&sessionID=lt444...
```

Comment: Yeah should've read the basic intro to the api more thoroughly! Thx michael johnson, you were alway my hero when I was a kid.